# Returning Results of BigQuery Script to Python Client

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery

As of Fall 2019, BigQuery supports [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting), which is great. What I can't figure out is whether the [Python client for BigQuery](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html) is capable of utilizing this new functionality yet.

For example, running the the following Python code:

```
client = bigquery.Client()
QUERY = """
BEGIN
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE t0 AS
        SELECT * FROM my_dataset.my_table WHERE foo < 1;

    SELECT SUM(bar) AS bar_sum FROM t0;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t0;
END;
"""

query_job = client.query(QUERY)
rows = query_job.result()
```

... returns an `google.cloud.bigquery.table._EmptyRowIterator` object even though I am able to see the statements in the SQL script have successfully run from BigQuery's web UI.

**How do I return the results from SELECT statement in this standard SQL script to the Python client?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is supported but you need to take into account the following piece of [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#bigquery-scripting):

> Scripts are executed in BigQuery using jobs.insert, similar to any
>   other query, with the multi-statement script specified as the query
>   text. When a script executes, additional jobs, known as **child jobs**,
>   **are created for each statement in the script**. You can enumerate the
>   child jobs of a script by calling jobs.list, passing in the script’s
>   job ID as the parentJobId parameter.
>
> **When jobs.getQueryResults is invoked on a script, it will return the**
>   **query results for the last SELECT, DML, or DDL statement to execute** in
>   the script, with no query results if none of the above statements have
>   executed. To obtain the results of all statements in the script,
>   enumerate the child jobs and call jobs.getQueryResults on each of
>   them.

As an example, I modified your script to query a public table: `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_stations`. This runs three child jobs:

[image]

where the **last one** drops the table and **does not return any row**:

[image]

That's why, if I run the Python file, I get something like `<google.cloud.bigquery.table._EmptyRowIterator object at 0x7f440aa33c88>`.

What we want is the **output result** of the middle **query**:

[image]

A quick test is to comment out the `DROP` statement and then iterate over the row(s) to get the result of `sum=6676`. So, what if we want the intermediate results? The answer, as in the previously cited docs, is to call [`jobs.list`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list) and pass the script job ID as the `parentJobId` parameter to get the child job IDs:

```py
for job in client.list_jobs(parent_job=query_job.job_id):
    print("Job ID: {}, Statement Type: {}".format(job.job_id, job.statement_type))
```

We use the [`list_jobs`](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.list_jobs) method and check [ID and statement type](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob):

```py
Job ID: script_job_80e...296_2, Statement Type: DROP_TABLE
Job ID: script_job_9a0...7fd_1, Statement Type: SELECT
Job ID: script_job_113...e13_0, Statement Type: CREATE_TABLE_AS_SELECT
```

Note that the suffix (0, 1, 2) indicates the execution order but we can add a double check to verify that the job is actually a `SELECT` statement before retrieving the results:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
QUERY = """
BEGIN
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE t0 AS
        SELECT name, bikes_count FROM `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_stations` WHERE bikes_count > 10;

    SELECT SUM(bikes_count) AS total_bikes FROM t0;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t0;
END;
"""

query_job = client.query(QUERY)
query_job.result()

for job in client.list_jobs(parent_job=query_job.job_id):  # list all child jobs
    # print("Job ID: {}, Statement Type: {}".format(job.job_id, job.statement_type))
    if job.statement_type == "SELECT":  # print the desired job output only
        rows = job.result()
        for row in rows:
            print("sum={}".format(row["total_bikes"]))
```

output:

```py
sum=6676
```