# Passing tuples to SQL query while unnesting

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to query a large BigQuery table to retrieve data from certain dates about barcodes in a store. There is a specified date for each of these barcodes (there are thousands of dates for each barcode in the BigQuery table, which makes it unpractical to only query on barcode). I have therefore created a list of tuples containing the barcodes and specific dates (only a very small subset):

```
date_and_barcode = [('A4630411929016393', datetime.date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4630411929716390', datetime.date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4630462735016271', datetime.date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4070460677116273', datetime.date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4070460701616276', datetime.date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4630460194116279', datetime.date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4630460205516276', datetime.date(2022, 10, 7)),
 ('A4630460214016271', datetime.date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4630460280316277', datetime.date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4630460281616271', datetime.date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4630450353216276', datetime.date(2022, 10, 11)),
 ('A4220452268816274', datetime.date(2022, 10, 9))]
```

My query today looks like this:

```
query="""
select   barcode,
         storeinfo1,
         storeinfo2,
         item1

         from `project.dataset.table`
         where barcode IN UNNEST(@label_list) and date in UNNEST(@date_list)
"""

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
query_parameters=[
         bigquery.ArrayQueryParameter("label_list", "STRING", label_list),
         bigquery.ArrayQueryParameter("date_list", "STRING", date_list),
            ]
        )
DATA = client.query(query, job_config=job_config).to_dataframe()
```

This obviously doesn't work since it will take all the possible combinations of barcodes and dates. I only want the combinations that match the list I have.

I tried this

```
query="""
select   barcode,
         storeinfo1,
         storeinfo2,
         item1

         from `project.dataset.table`
        where barcode in {} and Date in {} 
                                )

            """.format(UNNEST(date_and_barcode)[0], UNNEST(date_and_barcode)[1])

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
query_parameters=[
         bigquery.ArrayQueryParameter("date_and_barcode", "STRING", date_and_barcode),

            ]
        )
DATA = client.query(query, job_config=job_config).to_dataframe()
```

and

```
query="""
select   barcode,
         storeinfo1,
         storeinfo2,
         item1

         from `project.dataset.table`
        where barcode in UNNEST(@{}) and Date in UNNEST(@{})
                                )

            """.format(list(zip(*date_and_labels))[0], list(zip(*date_and_labels))[1])

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
query_parameters=[
         bigquery.ArrayQueryParameter("date_and_barcode", "STRING", date_and_barcode),

            ]
        )
DATA = client.query(query, job_config=job_config).to_dataframe()
```

None worked!

I would be grateful for hints on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using [tuple syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#tuple_syntax) in your query.

> (barcode, date) IN UNNEST(date_and_barcode)

```sql
DECLARE date_and_barcode DEFAULT [('A4630411929016393', date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4630411929716390', date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4630462735016271', date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4070460677116273', date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4070460701616276', date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4630460194116279', date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4630460205516276', date(2022, 10, 7)),
 ('A4630460214016271', date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4630460280316277', date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4630460281616271', date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4630450353216276', date(2022, 10, 11)),
 ('A4220452268816274', date(2022, 10, 9))];

WITH sample_data AS (
    SELECT 'A4630460194116279' barcode, DATE '2022-10-09' date
)
SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE (barcode, date) IN UNNEST(date_and_barcode);
```

**Query results**

[image]

---

**Python Example**

```py
date_and_barcode = [('A4630411929016393', datetime.date(2022, 10, 9)),
 ('A4630411929716390', datetime.date(2022, 10, 9)),
 # ...  same as list of tuples in your question
 ('A4630450353216276', datetime.date(2022, 10, 11)),
 ('A4220452268816274', datetime.date(2022, 10, 9))
]

date_and_barcode = ",".join("('%s','%s')" % tup for tup in date_and_barcode)

query=f"""
  select barcode,
         storeinfo1,
         storeinfo2,
         item1
   from `project.dataset.table`
  where (barcode, date) IN UNNEST([{date_and_barcode}])
"""
print(query)
```

Comment: This works like a charm. But...when run in BQ it creates two query results. One for the declaration, the other for the actual results. Do you know how to access only the results. I am working in python.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes, `date_and_barcode` s are stored in another table in your real dataset ?

Comment: They are stored in a list created prior to the query

Comment: If the list is not big  and you want to run the query in a single statement, you might consider python code I've updated.

Comment: or, this might be helpful if you want to get a result from BigQuery script which consists of multiple statements. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59806304/returning-results-of-bigquery-script-to-python-client